# android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm getting the error from the title in my Android project. I have searched for similar issues, which had me checkboxes casting, which seems ok, and also to clean and rebuild the project, which it did not work.

The app is crashing when I click the "Register" Button after a register form that contains EditTexts (for username, email and password) and Checkboxes for the user to pick multiple items. What should I do next?

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Sport> sports = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Sport> selectedSports = new ArrayList<>();

private void initializeSports(){
    String[] sportsArray = getResources().getStringArray(array.sportsName);

    for (int i = 0; i < sportsArray.length; i++){
        sports.add(new Sport(i + 1, sportsArray[i]));
    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_register);

    initializeSports();


    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(id.etEmail);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(id.etPassword);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(id.bRegister);

    final CheckBox cbSoccer = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbSoccer);
    cbSoccer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });

    final CheckBox cbFootball = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbFootball);
    cbFootball.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });

    final CheckBox cbBasket = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbBasket);
    cbBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });
    final CheckBox cbTennis = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbTennis);
    cbTennis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });
    final CheckBox cbSwimming = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbSwimming);
    cbSwimming.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });
    final CheckBox cbGym = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbGym);
    cbGym.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });
    final CheckBox cbOther = (CheckBox) findViewById(id.cbOther);
    cbOther.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            selectItem(v);
        }
    });


    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            final String passcode = etPassword.getText().toString();

            selectItem(v);

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, email, passcode, selectedSports, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}

public void selectItem(View v){

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.cbSoccer:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(0));


            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(0));
    } break;

        case R.id.cbFootball:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(1));
            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(1));
            } break;

        case R.id.cbTennis:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(2));

            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(2));
            } break;

        case R.id.cbSwimming:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(3));


            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(3));
            } break;

        case R.id.cbGym:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(4));


            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(4));
            } break;

        case R.id.cbBasket:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(5));


            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(5));
            } break;

        case R.id.cbOther:

            if(checked){
                selectedSports.add(sports.get(6));

            } else{
                selectedSports.remove(sports.get(6));
            } break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the view to CheckBox in your selectItem(v) method and in your listener

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectItem(v);
    }
});
```

You are passing the View v, i.e, the clicked button, so the button can not be casted to CheckBox.

Remove this line from listener

```
selectItem(v);
```

and it will be alright.

Answer (score 0):

In the `selectItem(v)` method the view passed to the method is an instance of `Button` since it is written in the `onClickListener` of button

If you want to do the same first make a check in `selectItem(View v)` method

```
if(v instanceof CheckBox) {
      boolean checked = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
}
```

Then proceed with the rest of code